# Cannot get signed in users of Azure AD tenant using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the list of user sign-ins into my Azure AD tenant using Microsoft Graph.

I'm using the below query to get them.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns
```

But I'm getting the error like this: [image: Error]

I understood that I'm missing a few permissions but  I'm the global administrator of my tenant.
I hope it is enough and no other permissions are needed. Still if needed, where to assign them?

Can anyone help me out with proper steps? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Even you are global admin, you must give `AuditLog.Read.All` and `Directory.Read.All` permissions to get list of sign-ins. Try giving them in **Modify Permissions** tab in Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Comment: Thanks but can you guide me through the steps of how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned, even if you have ***global administrator*** role, you still need to assign permissions while querying in **Microsoft Graph Explorer**.

As the error says, to get list of sign-in logs, you need permissions like ***AuditLog.Read.All*** and ***Directory.Read.All***.

Currently, it requires ***admin consent*** even after assigning both the permissions. As you are ***global admin***, you can directly accept the consent.

To know how to assign those permissions and consent them, please check the steps below:

***Go to Microsoft Graph Explorer -> Modify Permissions -> Select required permission -> Consent -> Accept***

[image]

[image]

***After assigning those permissions, you will get list of sign-in logs successfully without any errors.***

[image]

For more information in detail, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It really helped !